# How to reuse an attribute as a directive in react

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angular-directive

something like

```
<div my-dir></div>
<p my-dir></p>
```

Whatever element has `my-dir` can do something common.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reusable function. In react there is no concept called directive but components. This can be easily achieved by normal JavaScript functions with JSX syntax.